# How to merge two images and show in an Image control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

there is a frame with the full size and an inner picture with smaller size in my app. I want the inner one be inside and on top of the frame. So this is what I did:

```
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Frame.png", UriKind.Relative));
var frame = new BitmapImage();
frame.SetSource(resourceStream.Stream);

WriteableBitmap finalImage = new WriteableBitmap(frame);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BitmapImage innerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format("Assets/Pages/{0}.png", page), UriKind.Relative));
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Height = innerImage.PixelHeight;
    image.Width = innerImage.PixelWidth;
    image.Source = innerImage;

    TranslateTransform translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    translateTransform.X = 52;
    translateTransform.Y = 60;

    finalImage.Render(image, translateTransform);
    finalImage.Invalidate();

    finalImage.SaveJpeg(memoryStream, frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

    PagePicture.Source = finalImage;
}
```

But I only see the frame without the inner image.. I guess that maybe behind the frame.
How can I solve this?

Or maybe I can have two controls one on another without merging? let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this link will guide you. Please [visit here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D388A3652195E9E8!206&authkey=!AADCpamrequ5BwA).
For details description please go through [MSDN SAmple](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/merge-multiple-on-a-single-e7cdaa76). Both are same but you can get description here.

Now Try this

```
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Inner Image
            BitmapImage innerImage = new BitmapImage();
            innerImage.SetSource(System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(innerImage);

            //Frame Images
            BitmapImage finalImage = new BitmapImage();
            finalImage.SetSource(System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("White.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            WriteableBitmap wbFinal = new WriteableBitmap(finalImage);

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Height = innerImage.PixelHeight;
            image.Width = innerImage.PixelWidth;
            image.Source = innerImage;

            // TranslateTransform                      
            TranslateTransform tf = new TranslateTransform();
            tf.X = 52;
            tf.Y = 60;
            wbFinal.Render(image, tf);

            wbFinal.Invalidate();
            wbFinal.SaveJpeg(mem, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            mem.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Show image.               
            PagePicture.Source = wbFinal;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit. you know, my code also is base on that example, and I read it. but didn't work for my case